# Some of my fields do not show on a rd-mailform.php

Tags: php, mail-form

I'm a bit new to `php`.

I attached `rd-mailform.php` to my site and it sends and redirects perfectly.

Issue is when I picked it up it only had two fields, email and message, so I tried adding name and phone which where in my `html` form, but can't get these 2 new fields to appear in the email I receive, trying understand what I am missing.

Code is as follows

```css
<?php

$recipients = '';
//$recipients = '';

try {
    require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    preg_match_all("/([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/", $recipients, $addresses, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    if (!count($addresses[0])) {
        die('MF001');
    }

    if (preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        die('MF002');
    }

    $template = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

    if (isset($_POST['form-type'])) {
        switch ($_POST['form-type']){
            case 'contact':
                $subject = 'A message from your site visitor';
                break;
            case 'subscribe':
                $subject = 'Subscribe request';
                break;
            case 'order':
                $subject = 'Order request';
                break;
            default:
                $subject = 'A message from your site visitor';
                break;
        }
    }else{
        die('MF004');
    }
    
     if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{NameState} -->", "<!-- #{FromName} -->"],
            ["Name:", $_POST['name']],
            $template);
    }else{
        die('MF006');
    }

    
     if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{PhoneState} -->", "<!-- #{FromPhone} -->"],
            ["Phone:", $_POST['phone']],
            $template);
    }else{
        die('MF005');
    }


    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{FromState} -->", "<!-- #{FromEmail} -->"],
            ["Email:", $_POST['email']],
            $template);
    }else{
        die('MF003');
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $template = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{MessageState} -->", "<!-- #{MessageDescription} -->"],
            ["Message:", $_POST['message']],
            $template);
    }

    preg_match("/(<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->)(.|\n)+(<!-- #{EndInfo} -->)/", $template, $tmp, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "name" && $key != "phone" && $key != "email" && $key != "message" && $key != "form-type" && !empty($value)){
            $info = str_replace(
                ["<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->", "<!-- #{InfoState} -->", "<!-- #{InfoDescription} -->"],
                ["", ucfirst($key) . ':', $value],
                $tmp[0][0]);

            $template = str_replace("<!-- #{EndInfo} -->", $info, $template);
        }
    }

    $template = str_replace(
        ["<!-- #{Subject} -->", "<!-- #{SiteName} -->"],
        [$subject, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']],
        $template);

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    $mail->FromName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    foreach ($addresses[0] as $key => $value) {
        $mail->addAddress($value[0]);
    }

    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($template);

    if (isset($_FILES['attachment'])) {
        foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key], $_FILES['Attachment']['name'][$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    $mail->send();
    header('Location: http://www.mut-con.co.za/thankyou.html');  //Redirect

    die('MF000');
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    die('MF254');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('MF255');
}
?>
```

Like I said the form sends fine, just need it to send name and phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the form that's posting to the php file has the fields named the same (same case, no spaces, etc) and have the "name" property specified. If you only have "id" (which is used to identify the field uniquely on the HTML page, but is not used when submitting the form), the field data don't be posted.

Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see your posted form data on the server side, and use the developer tools network tab in your browser to see what was sent over the wire. That will help you debug many of these types of issues very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much Douglas Phillips testing really helped, cause i realized my form was posting and receiving all the fields from browser to the server so started looking elsewhere, turns out I forgot to update the template that delivers the mail. Egg in the face moment here